# How can I handle a bunch of achievements in a game?

Tags: game-design, achievements

Take for example Team Fortress 2.  There are a huge load of achievements, and I'm wondering how the manages all of them. And since there's a lot of achievements, I'd also like to know how it "knows" you've achieved one.

Basically, how can the game handle a huge achievement system?  Is there some special process? Are there hundreds and hundreds of boolean variables all over the code, waiting for certain conditions to be met, then ,*Bam*, achievement?

If there are several approaches, what are they?

Comment: There are lots of ways to handle this, and since TF2 isn't open source, we'll never know, although since it is a steam game, it must use their API, check it out... https://partner.steamgames.com/documentation/... I guess the point is there is no right or wrong answer...

Comment: Is your real question: what is a good system to detect if a specific situation is happening? I'm also bazzled by the number of situations they have to track for all the TF2 achievements.

Comment: you have to remember that you wont be able to achieve all the achievements all the time - so depending on your character choice / level / weapon etc... the total achievements available (while still impressively large) is still somewhat smaller than the total amount in the game

Comment: @RoyT. Yeah. But my question came out worded wrong, sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think one method to implement something like this could be **event-driven**. This means, you will have points in your code where specific events are called. It must be somewhat extended to allow to **pass parameters**, but I think it’s not uncommon that event-systems can handle parameters.

First you will have to **define some events in your code** that can happen. This is the position where you thought of all the `if`-conditions. E.g. when a player kills somebody, an event for killing somebody will be raised.

I do not know Team Fortress 2, but it’s a shooter, so I choose some shooter examples. In the code examples the first parameters always is the event name and the later ones are an indefinite list of parameters (this event takes).

- player kills another player (`callEvent('kills-player', curPlayer)`)
- player just disarmed a bomb (`callEvent('disarms-bomb', curPlayer)`)
- player reached point X (`callEvent('reaches-point', curPlayer, somePointOnMap)`)
- player saved another players live (`callEvent('saved-player', curPlayer, rescuedPlayer)`)

So it’s not boolean variables throughout your code, but specific events that will be called.

It’s now up to a totally different programmer at a totally different position in the code to either **use or not use these events** (called *listening* to them). You might also save events in a database to be able to count them (and give awards when something occured 10 times). This will also be done by the programmer who catches the events with a method like the following. It takes:

- the event-name as first parameter
- a lambda-function to handle the event as the second parameter. The lambda-function can catch all arguments we passed to the event handler before.

Code example:

```
listenToEvent('kills-player', function(player) {
    database.incrementKillPlayerCount(player);

    if (database.killPlayerCount(player) == 10) {
        player.awardWithAchievement("You killed 10 enemies!");
    }
});
```

So this little function can now cope with events that were raised in a totally different place of th code. And it will award a player with the correct achievement if needed.

### Addition

As it sounds like TF2's system was very flexible: You might also implement the event-system in a manner that it watches for several situations to occur within the same time or within a timespan. Of course you had to change it a little to maintain a small buffer or similar for several seconds or milliseconds and then map calls like `listenToEvent(array('kills-player', 'disarms-bomb') function() {})` to the buffer.